# Module 'cv2' has no 'VideoCapture' member

Tags: python, opencv

```py
import numpy
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break


    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This my code andi get this error
1.Module 'cv2' has no 'VideoCapture' member
2.Module 'cv2' has no 'imshow' member
3.Module 'cv2' has no 'waitKey' member
4.Module 'cv2' has no 'destroyAllWindows' member

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQStj.png)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you use VSCode, you can try using this code:

```
from cv2 import cv2
```

Comment: this import is wrong and will throw an error: `ImportError: Bindings generation error. Submodule name should always start with a parent module name. Parent name: cv2.cv2. Submodule name: cv2` -- it used to work in older versions of opencv, __by accident__

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error in my code, I followed the steps below and it worked.

1. Install OpenCV using `pip install opencv-python`
2. While importing, do it like this: `from cv2 import cv2`

Comment: same here, that import will throw `ImportError: Bindings generation error. Submodule name should always start with a parent module name. Parent name: cv2.cv2. Submodule name: cv2`

Answer (score 1):

Import statements shouldn’t be in the same line.

```
import numpy
import cv2
```

Also make sure that you have installed opencv using

```
pip install opencv-python
```